# Session gets null after few minutes in Next-auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I'm using Next-auth to authenticate the users in my application, When I logging in to the application, the session data comes, but after refresh or any re-rendering happens, the session data returns null. I'm using MongoDB to authenticate the data with the back end. The code in **app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.js** looks like,

```
import { MongoClient } from "mongodb";
import CredentialsProvider from "next-auth/providers/credentials";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import NextAuth from "next-auth/next";

export const authOptions = {
  session: { strategy: "jwt" },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Credentials",
      credentials: {
        email: { label: "Email", type: "email", placeholder: "Email" },
        password: {
          label: "Password",
          type: "password",
          placeholder: "Password",
        },
      },
      async authorize(credentials, req) {
        try {
          const client = await MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGO_URL, {
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
          });
          const db = client.db("test");
          const user = await db
            .collection("users")
            .findOne({ email: credentials.email });

          if (!user) throw new Error("User is not found!");

          if (user) {
            const checkPassword = await bcrypt.compare(
              credentials.password,
              user.password
            );
            if (!checkPassword) throw new Error("Password is incorrect!");
          }

          return {
            id: 1,
            userId: user._id,
            name: user.name,
            username: user.username,
            color: user.color
          };
        } catch (error) {
          throw new Error(error);
        }
      },
    }),
  ],
  callbacks: {
    jwt: async ({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) => {
      if (user) {
        token.user = user;
      }
      // console.log({ token, user, account }, "in jwt");
      return token;
    },

    session: async ({ session, user, token }) => {
      // console.log({ session, token, user }, "in session");
      return {
        ...session,
        user: token.user,
      };
    },
  },
};

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions);
export { handler as POST, handler as GET };
```

I don't get why this is happening. Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: how do you know it gets `null`?

Comment: @Hatana By consoling the session object and the UI elements depending on that session gets broken.

Comment: Do you have a middleware to handle refresh?

Comment: @grekier No I didn't configure any middleware. Is this happening because of it ?

Comment: I think so. See https://next-auth.js.org/tutorials/securing-pages-and-api-routes#nextjs-middleware

Comment: @grekier how can middlewares affect the session?

Comment: @Hatana Any other suggestions ?

Comment: I believe the middleware does a refresh of the session